# Machine Certificate Key File Artifacts

Tags: certificates, windows

When a new machine certificate is imported with a private key a MachineKey file is generated in "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys".  When using the certificate mmc snapin or removing a certificate with powershell's `Remove-Item` the MachineKey file is left behind.  What are the implications to the artifacts existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows manages certificates and private keys separately. Each certificate *may* point to a private key; several certificates can point to the same key. Each such "pointer" is given as the name of the Cryptographic Service Provider (that morally contains the key), and the key name within that CSP. Windows does not keep track of how many certificates point to a given private key, and indeed this is not completely defined (especially since certificate stores can be extended with custom DLL). The main consequence is that when you delete a certificate, the private key stays there.

Private keys *can* be destroyed, but this requires calling the Win32 function [CryptAcquireContext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379886(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `CRYPT_DELETEKEYSET` flag. Alternatively, you can use the `certutil -key` command to list private keys, and `certutil -delkey` to delete them. Neither of these commands is described in the [Certutil documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc732443.aspx) but you can get some help with `certutil -key -?` and `certutil -delkey -?`. In both case you may need to specify an explicit CSP name with the `-csp` option (use `certutil -csplist` to get the list of CSP installed on your machine).

Anyway, the security implication is the following: **don't rely on private key deletion**. A private key is a sensitive object; it must be handled with care. The *normal* lifecycle for a "machine key" is to be generated on the machine where it will be used, and never leave it. You should arrange for *never* to have to delete a private key. The need for private key deletion usually arises from people generating keys on their desktop system, to manage certificate enrollment from the comfort of their desk, and then transferring the private key and certificate to the system that will actually use it. This is poor practice, because it may leave traces of the private key on the desktop system.

Private key deletion is not very easy (as shown above: custom C program or undocumented command), and even when it works, it really is a file deletion, which does not actually ensure that the data no longer exists; file deletion merely marks the corresponding space as "free for reuse" but does not wipe it proactively.

Comment: I would guess that Windows stores private keys as encrypted files.  So if the private key data is deleted only the encrypted form would stay in memory?

Comment: Windows stores private keys with encryption, but the encryption is ultimately based on the password of the account that owns the key. If a machine can boot up alone and use a private key, then that machine necessarily "knows" everything that is needed to access the private key, and thus the key can be recovered. That private key encryption is there to defeat some attackers with only partial access (they can read _some_ files, not all of them), to block a few unsophisticated malware that scan RAM brutally, and, of course, to make a show of "having sprinkled crypto everywhere".